# How to get an access token from an api using ajax without error

Tags: javascript, rest, api

I am trying to connect to an api that has credentials that must be passed through the body and have a basic auth. I can't connect to it and it gives me a 403 error using ajax. These are the instructions to connect:

1 - endpoint where they must authenticate:

https://ngapi.freedompop.mx/api/auth/token/credentials/xx

As I had mentioned, it is necessary to use a Basic Auth with the following credentials:

Username: 4148974 Password: GmiA2SspqT23RerXUts3xd4cCClnM6cl

In addition to this in the body part, the following parameters must be sent:

username: xxx password: jvgXvHBrTrxkKJStxx

This is my code:

```
   type: "POST",
   url: "https://ngapi.freedompop.mx/api/auth/token/credentials",
   dataType: 'json',
   async: false,
   headers: {
   "Authorization": "Basic " + ("4148974" + ":" + "GmiA2SspqT23RerXUts3xd4cCClnM6cl")
 },
   data: {"username": "xxx", "password": "jvgXvHBrTrxkKJSt"},
   success: function (response){
   alert('Thanks for your comment!');
   var tokenct = response.acces_token;
   }, function(error){
        console.log(error);
    }   
});

});
```